# Image Thumbnail Load behaviour (Pretty Photo Lightbox functionality preferred)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, photo-gallery, prettyphoto

I'm trying to make a picture portfolio like the first demo example on this page http://www.no-margin-forerrors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto . However, instead of have it invoke an image when clicked it takes me to another page, I'd like it to have a pop up image instead. I had already checked possibilities in theme settings but none available.

This is the link http://tile.johnzuh.com/unsere-fliesen/  to the Page with this behaviour. You will realise that once u click on the gallery image item it sends you to another page using this

```
<a itemprop="url" class="eltdf-pli-link" href="http://tile.johnzuh.com/portfolio-item/home-interior-2/" target="_self"></a>
```

linked element to image. This is an unexpected behaviour

### How it should behave

I would appreciate a behaviour similar to that on this page instead http://tile.johnzuh.com/portfolio-item/plava-identity-design-4/

Once you click on an image it should invoke a bigger image from thumbnail. 
I see it uses

```
<a itemprop="image" title="portfolio-single-13" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="http://tile.johnzuh.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/portfolio-single-13.jpg">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://tile.johnzuh.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/portfolio-single-13.jpg" alt="s" />
</a>
```

It uses the prettyPhoto element instead of linking to the href. How do i adopt this ? Some quick workarounds, examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Issue was solved by changing some dynamic settings in theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by changing some dynamic settings in theme.